# How can I compare an NSMutableArray with a c array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an NSMutableArray and I want to test it against multiple "Win" cases.
Meaning, I want to test each 3 integer C array, against the NSMutableArray and see if the ints found in the C array are found in the NSMutablearray

These are my C arrays:

```
// horizontal
int winCaseHorizontal1[3] = {9, 1, 2};
int winCaseHorizontal2[3] = {3, 4, 5};
int winCaseHorizontal3[3] = {6, 7, 8};

// verticle
int winCaseVerticle1[3] = {9, 3, 6};
int winCaseVerticle2[3] = {1, 4, 7};
int winCaseVerticle3[3] = {2, 5, 8};

// diaganol
int winCaseDiagonal1[3] = {9, 4, 8};
int winCaseDiagonal2[3] = {2, 4, 6};
```

I want to test the numbers say in the array winCaseHorizontal1, and see if those numbers are found in my NSMutableArray.

I've read about testing if two NSMutableArrays are equal, but this is quite different.
One; this is comparing a c array with an NSMutable,
Two; I don't care if they are equal, I just want to see if the c array ints are found in the NSMutable.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There's no nifty tool for this -- you have to write the obvious code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your arrays and can find if element exists in `NSMutableArray`.

```
-(BOOL)elementFound{

 for(NSNumber *number in mutableArray)
 {
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(winCaseHorizontal1) / sizeof(int); i++)
   {
     if([number integerValue] == winCaseHorizontal1[i]){
         return YES;
     }
   }



   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(winCaseHorizontal2) / sizeof(int); i++)
   {
     if([number integerValue] == winCaseHorizontal2[i]){
         return YES;
     }
   }


  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(winCaseHorizontal3) / sizeof(int); i++)
   {
     if([number integerValue] == winCaseHorizontal3[i]){
         return YES;
     }
   }

//other arrays
 }
   return NO;
}
```

If you want index or elements which found in your c arrays than you can make another array and add the index or elements in that array and return it at end of function.

**EDIT:** As BryanChen suggested a faster way to do that is make and `NSSet` from c array and check if mutableArray element exist of not.

```
   NSMutableSet *winCaseHorizontalSet1 = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(winCaseHorizontal1) / sizeof(int); i++)
   {
     [winCaseHorizontalSet1 addObject:@(winCaseHorizontal1[i])];
   }


  for(NSNumber *number in mutableArray)
  {
   BOOL isContain = [winCaseHorizontalSet1 containsObject:number]; 
   if(isContain) return YES; 

   //other set of c arrays
  }
```

Comment: this is a very slow approach. Use `NSSet` if you only want to test existence.

Comment: @BryanChen thanks but to put c array in `NSSet` we have to iterate through all arrays or is there any other way to make `NSSet` from c arrays

Comment: you only need to iterate through all arrays once and save the `NSSet`